# Can't redirect with REACT-ROUTER-DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've got this search method where I want to redirect the user after searching. The issue is that it does not do anything and I don't know why. this.props.history IS defined but the "location" property of the object "history" does not seem to change accordingly to what i put in the parameters of the push method ('./connexion') ... The URL does not change neither. The search method IS binded and I use `export default withRouter(SearchBar);` to access the history via props.  Knowing that I use exactly the same thing (this.props.history.push() and withRouter) in other files and it is working correctly ... I use `"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"` with browserHistory.

```
search(event) {
if (this.state.location === null) {
    this.setState({ geosuggestId: 'geosuggest-input-alert' });
} else if (this.state.subjects.length === 0) {
    this.setState({ matieresButtonId: 'matieres-button-alert' });
} else {
    console.log(this.props.parent);
    if (this.props.parent === 'Homepage') {
        console.log(this.props.history);
        this.props.history.push('/connexion');
    }
}
}
```

Full file :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Geosuggest from 'react-geosuggest';
import SearchBySubjectsModal from './modals/search_by_subjects_modal';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

/**
 * Search bar for parent to search for profs
 */
class SearchBar extends Component {

constructor(props) {

super(props);

this.state = {
    location: null,
    subjects: [],
    level: 'Collège',
    matieresButtonId: 'matieres-button',
    geosuggestId: 'geosuggest-input'
}

this.onSuggestSelect = this.onSuggestSelect.bind(this);
this.setSubjects = this.setSubjects.bind(this);
this.search = this.search.bind(this);
}

/**
 * if the state for subjects and location is not null, then stop     fields warning
 */
componentDidUpdate() {
if (this.state.subjects.length > 0) {
    if (this.state.matieresButtonId !== 'matieres-button')
        this.setState({ matieresButtonId: 'matieres-button' });
}
if (this.state.location !== null) {
    if (this.state.geosuggestId !== 'geosuggest-input')
        this.setState({ geosuggestId: 'geosuggest-input' });
}
}

/**
 * set the state when choosing a location
 * @param {*} suggest 
 */
onSuggestSelect(suggest) {
this.setState({ location: suggest });
}

/**
 * set the state when choosing subjects
 * @param {*} suggest 
 */
setSubjects(subjects, level) {
this.setState({ subjects, level });
}

/**
 * Search method
 * Check if subjects or location are null (is so, show warnings)
 * If no warnings, perform search and redirect to search page
 * @param {*} event 
 */
search(event) {
if (this.state.location === null) {
    this.setState({ geosuggestId: 'geosuggest-input-alert' });
} else if (this.state.subjects.length === 0) {
    this.setState({ matieresButtonId: 'matieres-button-alert' });
} else {
    console.log(this.props.parent);
    if (this.props.parent === 'Homepage') {
        console.log(this.props.history);
        this.props.history.push('/connexion');
    }
}
}

/**
 * Uses GeoSuggest (google places api) to choose a town
 * Uses Search By Subject modal to choose subjects
 */
render() {
return (
    <div className="container" id="search-bar" >
        <div className="text-center">
            <form action="">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <Geosuggest
                            queryDelay={150}
                            autoActivateFirstSuggest={true}
                            inputClassName={this.state.geosuggestId}
                            placeholder="Où ?"
                            country="fr"
                            onSuggestSelect={this.onSuggestSelect} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <Link to="/">
                            <button data-toggle="modal" data-target=".choose-subject-modal" className="btn clickable" id={this.state.matieresButtonId}>
                                <i className="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>  Matières ?
                            </button>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <Link to="/">
                            <button type="submit" className="btn clickable" id="search-button" onClick={this.search}>
                                <h5 id="search-btn-txt"><i className="fa fa-search"></i>  Trouver</h5>
                            </button>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <SearchBySubjectsModal search={this.search} location={this.state.location} setSubjects={this.setSubjects} />
        </div>
    </div>
);
};
}





export default withRouter(SearchBar);
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using react-router v4. This version of react router has shifted towards much more declarative approach than before. How does this shift affect redirection? Simplest way to redirect would be to render `<Redirect>` react router component. So how would whole thing work? Your search once finished would change state part `searchResult:` from false to for instance list of results. This would cause rerender. Your components would when they find non false value in state.searchResult would render `<Redirect>` component pointing to your search results route.

I have been vague about state handling since there are many ways to handle state in react app.

You may look at the [authentication example in react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) which does pretty much same thing as you need (it only performs authenitcation instead of search)

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer ! I was thinking of it, but it seems to me to be kind of a hack doing that :) What is also very weird to me is that this way is perfectly working in other comonents but does not work with this one :s

Comment: I do not think it is hack, it may look strange until one gets used to typical react way: user actions do not cause direct ui changes, user actions result in state change, and then react components render themselves accordingly to new state,